# how to split/show indivisual file in multiple file input tag in html and associate input with each file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a project, in which I am giving a website platform for users to  upload their files on server and server will print those files using hardware printer.
For instance if a user is uploading a file for printing then he will need to select

- **number of copies**
- **black&White or colored**

With repect to each file.
 With the normal file input tag i can able to select multiple files and i use **copies and colorscheme** once in the form like below
[My file input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M0pa.png)

I want something like this,
[This way i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTocA.png)
here each time i select file a new field should generate with those two inputs and when i click submit all files should be processed using php with respective copies and colourscheme for indivisual file. I seen many plugins like **uploadify**, **jQuery File Upload**, **Plupload**, **Krajee Bootstrap File Input Demo** etc.
But modifying these plugins as per my requirements is very difficult for me since i am beginner to jQuery
I want something as simple as possible even with a dull interface. I would really appreciate if someone can help me to sort out my problem.
Thank you